# Django 1.4 not recognizing my app

Tags: django, settings

I am using django 1.4, and the app.module name does not seem to be working as expected for me. My settings.py has the app included as "survey.surveys".

Here is the django shell dump for an import I attempted through a preexisting file. The error says No module named ....

```
from survey.surveys.views.db import mobile_survey1 
 Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<console>", line 1, in <module>   File "/home/pjain/dev/survey/survey/surveys/views/db.py", line 6, in <module>
from survey.surveys.models import Survey, Section, Question, Option   
 File "/home/pjain/dev/survey/survey/surveys/views/survey.py", line 7, in <module>
from survey.surveys.models import Survey, Section, Question, Option 
 ImportError: No module named surveys.models
```

However, when I copied and pasted the exact import which breaks, it imports fine in the shell.

> from survey.surveys.models import Survey, Section, Question, Option

How can I fix this import in my project?

Comment: Try from surveys.models import... Also try this in your installed apps setting

Comment: Maybe you deal with cyclic imports.

Comment: is there an __init__.py in surveys ?

Comment: @Jingo - yes I should have mentioned I tried plain old surveys.models and that gives the same error. However, I can't even get the shell to import it like that.

Comment: @goliney - I don't think so, but how could I check?

Comment: can you show your app structure? in particular how surveys.survey is being called, and how surveys.models is defined .@Priyeshj

Comment: I have no idea what is wrong, but my app works perfectly well with app level access (from surveys.models import *), but the django shell works only with project level access (from survey.surveys.models import *). I have a feeling that it might have something to do with python path / wsgi settings, but I am just bypassing manual tests completely in the shell for now and working directly on the dev server due to time constraints. However, if anyone knows more about this, I would love to know more.